# Creating a Singleton NSMutableArray

Tags: ios

I am trying to do a Singleton NSMutableArray, but the count function always shows 0 elements. I guess it is not receiving well the object.

This is the code that i have created.

```
//VariableStore.h
@interface VariableStore : NSObject
{
    NSMutableArray *pruebaGlobal;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *pruebaGlobal;
+ (VariableStore *)sharedInstance;
- (NSMutableArray*)pruebaGlobal;
@end

//VariableStore.m
@implementation VariableStore
@synthesize pruebaGlobal;
+ (VariableStore *)sharedInstance
{
    // the instance of this class is stored here
    static VariableStore *myInstance = nil;

    // check to see if an instance already exists
    if (nil == myInstance) {
        myInstance  = [[[self class] alloc] init];
        myInstance.pruebaGlobal = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:100];
    }
    // return the instance of this class
    return myInstance;
}

- (NSMutableArray*)pruebaGlobal{
    return pruebaGlobal;
}

@end

//ViewController.m

NSMutableArray *p = [[VariableStore sharedInstance] pruebaGlobal];
p = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                   [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Sí", @"No", nil, nil, nil],
                   [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Súbita", @"Fluctuante", @"Progresiva", nil, nil],
nil];

NSLog(@"%d", [[[VariableStore sharedInstance] pruebaGlobal] count]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting aside the misuse of `nil` within your construction of arrays, your code simply does not ever add anything to the array you are getting the count of. Try this:

```
NSMutableArray *p = [[VariableStore sharedInstance] pruebaGlobal];
[p addObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Sí", @"No", [NSNull null], [NSNull null], nil]];
[p addObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Súbita", @"Fluctuante", @"Progresiva", [NSNull null], nil]];
```

As for the property you synthesize, you specify it as a retained property and then you explicitly define a getter for it but not a setter. If you declare a property as retained, you can either let the compiler take care of both getter and setter, or write both yourself, but not just one or the other. My suggestion, just remove the explicit getter: `- (NSMutableArray*)pruebaGlobal` from the header and implementation files.

Answer (score 0):

There is at least 2 problems with this part of the code :

```
NSMutableArray *p = [[VariableStore sharedInstance] pruebaGlobal];
p = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
               [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Sí", @"No", nil, nil, nil],
               [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Súbita", @"Fluctuante", @"Progresiva", nil, nil], nil];
```

First : `[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Sí", @"No", nil, nil, nil]`
`arrayWithObjects` can only take object and `nil` is not an object it is used to terminate the list of augments. If you want to insert the concept of `nil` into a `NSArray` you need to insert `[NSNull null]` which is a singleton object that exist specially for that use.

The Other problem is the use of `p`  :
You are getting a reference to your `NSMutableArray` pruebaGlobal and then you replace the content of your pointer `p` with the address of an other new array. So `p` now point to a different object that `pruebaGlobal`.

The way to correct this would be like this :

```
NSMutableArray *p = [[VariableStore sharedInstance] pruebaGlobal];  
[p addObject:@"test object"];
NSLog(@"%d", [[[VariableStore sharedInstance] pruebaGlobal] count]);
```

Now you should have a count of 1.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the synthesized ivar for the property will be named `_pruebaGlobal`. But your `pruebaGlobal` method is returning the `pruebaGlobal` ivar.

Your code should be update to be:

```
//VariableStore.h
@interface VariableStore : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *pruebaGlobal;

+ (VariableStore *)sharedInstance;
- (NSMutableArray*)pruebaGlobal;

@end

//VariableStore.m
@implementation VariableStore

+ (VariableStore *)sharedInstance {
    // the instance of this class is stored here
    static VariableStore *myInstance = nil;

    // check to see if an instance already exists
    if (nil == myInstance) {
        myInstance  = [[[self class] alloc] init];
        myInstance.pruebaGlobal = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:100];
    }

    // return the instance of this class
    return myInstance;
}

@end
```

You don't need an ivar or the `@synthesize` line anymore with the modern Objective-C compiler (Xcode 4.4 or later). Both will be generated for you.

You don't need to implement the `pruebaGlobal` method - it will be synthesized for you.

The other half your issue is that you assign a totally new array to the `p` variable which has no effect on the `pruebaGlobal` property. You need to assign `p` to the global if that is desired.

The line:

```
NSMutableArray *p = [[VariableStore sharedInstance] pruebaGlobal];
```

assigns your empty global array to `p`. You then do:

```
p = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:...
```

which assigned a new array to `p`. You then try to log the unmodified global.

You need to add:

```
[VariableStore sharedInstance].pruebaGlobal = p;
```

Comment: It is true that a lot of code is not needed with newer Xcode, but `your first sentence is false`, the way he wrote his code `@synthesize` won't create an iVar and the property will be tie with the `iVar` that have the same name as the property.

Comment: @VinceBurn I think you are right. It's the implicit `@sytenthisze` that gives the ivar with the underscore.

Comment: I was not certain too, I had to test it to double check. I always use the new ways so when dealing with the old way, I always double check.